# validation using ajax and codeigniter didn't work

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I tried checking whether the username is available or not, using ajax in codeigniter. But didn't work. I've tried a number of tutorials, but it still doesn't work. is there something wrong with my code below?

ajax:

```
$('#username').change(function(){
    var username = $('#username').val();
    if(username != ''){
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url('staff/admin/checkUsername');?>";
            method:"post",
            data:{username:username},
            success:function(data){
                $('#username_result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

controller:

```
function checkUsername($userName){
    if ($this->m_admin->checkUserexist($userName) == false) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

model:

```
function checkUserexist($userName) {
    $this->db->where('username', $userName);
    $this->db->from('tbuser');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not able to get data right? Because you are returning **BOOLEAN** on your controller. Which will be handled by the `data` on success on your ajax.. What is the flow of this if the user exist? What is the next action?

Comment: Thanks @Roshan for answering. I want to display a message that the username already exists.  I want to display a message in #username_result . which will be displayed in view , <span id="username_result"></span>

Comment: I think on your `controller` change `return true` to `return "Username already exists."` like that. Let's see if there's any changes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use too many `true` and `false`

Second, you are not getting `$userName` in the controller that is coming from ajax request

**Controller**

```
function checkUsername($userName){
  $userName = $this->input->post('username');
  $if_exists = $this->m_admin->checkUserexist($userName);
  if ($if_exists > 0) {
    echo json_encode('Exists');
  } else {
    echo json_encode('Not exists');
  }
}
```

**Model**

Check the number of rows

```
function checkUserexist($userName) {
   return $this->db->get_where('tbuser', ['username' => $userName])->num_rows();
}
```

**Ajax**

```
$('#username').change(function(){
var username = $('#username').val();
if(username != ''){
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url('staff/admin/checkUsername');?>";
        method:"post",
        data:{username:username},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data); //Exists OR Not exists
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in ajax code

```
$('#username').change(function(){
    var username = $('#username').val();
    if(username != ''){
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            complete: function () {
            },
            url:"<?php echo base_url('staff/admin/checkUsername');?>";
            method:"post",
            dataType: "json",
            data:({username:username}),
            success:function(data){
                //$('#username_result').html(data);
                alert(data.status)
            },
            error: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

try this in controller

```
function checkUsername($userName){
    if ($this->m_admin->checkUserexist($userName) == false) {
        $response_array['status'] = true;
        echo json_encode($response_array);
        exit();
    } else {
        $response_array['status'] = false;
        echo json_encode($response_array);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It works fine for me.Set input textbox id and name as same... 

Html :
<form id="myform" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

---

```
Codeigniter validation :
public function validate()
    {
        $json = array();
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pwd','Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $json = array(
                'success' => 0,
                'message' => 'Error occured',
                'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array()
            );
        } else {
            $data['email']=$this->input->post('email');
            $data['pwd']=$this->input->post('pwd');

            $json = array(
                'success' => 1,
                'message' => 'Data inserted successfully'
            );

        }

        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($json));
    }
```

---

```
Ajax call :
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).on('click', '#submit_btn', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dataString = $("#myform").serialize();
    var url="welcome/validate"
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>"+url,
            data:dataString,
            success: function(json) {
                try {
                    if (json['success'] == 1) {
                        alert(json['message']);
                    } else {
                        $('.error').hide();
                        var len = Object.keys(json['error']).length;
                        var error = json['error'];
                        if (len > 0) {
                            $.each(error, function( index, value ) {
                                if (value) {
                                    $('#'+index).after('<p class="error">'+value+"</p>");
                                }           
                            }); 
                        }                       
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log('Exception while request..');
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Error while request..');
            }
        });     
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Copy all code and run it in your server.Your output is look like this below image.Don't use span tag to display error message...https://ibb.co/TKyPBDH